# Get values from ng-repeat option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have multiples DropDownList or "options" to select. I need to get all the values of each option when the user click on "Guardar cambios

This is a part of my HTML:

```
<div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    Primer turno
                </div>
                <select>
                    <option ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" ng-selected="dia.valorInicio == horario" value="{{horario}}">{{horario}}</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    Último turno
                </div>
                <select>
                    <option ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" ng-selected="dia.valorFin == horario" value="{{horario}}">{{horario}}</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
```

The result is the following:

[image]

Someone told me that I need a model or something like that, but the data is a json from my database, so I need to use ng-repeat for each option.

**When the user click on "Guardar cambios" I have to send to my server each value that he selected.**

Someone know if I making in the right way and how to get all the value for each options?
Thanks!

**//EDIT//**

Now this is my view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Cambiar horarios">
<ion-content>
    <div class="list card" ng-repeat="dia in vm.dias">
        <div class="item item-divider" align="center">
            {{dia.nombre}}
        </div> 
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    Primer turno
                </div>
                <select  ng-model="selectedOption1" ng-options="horario for horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.guardarHorarioInicial($index)">
                </select>
                <!--<select>
                    <option ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" ng-selected="dia.valorInicio == horario" value="{{horario}}">{{horario}}</option>
                </select>-->
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    Último turno
                </div>
                <select ng-model="selectedOption2" ng-options="horario for horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.guardarHorarioFinal($index)">
                </select>
                <!--
                <select>
                    <option ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" ng-selected="dia.valorFin == horario" value="{{horario}}">{{horario}}</option>
                </select>-->
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="padding-horizontal"><button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="vm.guardarHorarios()"> Guardar horarios </button></div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is my controller with the function "guardarHorarioInicial" when the options change:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('example.cambiarhorarios')
    .controller('CambiarHorariosController', CambiarHorariosController);

CambiarHorariosController.$inject = ['$state', '$scope', 'cambiarHorariosService'];

function CambiarHorariosController($state, $scope, cambiarHorariosService ) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.estado = false;
    vm.estadoCambiarHorarios = false;
    vm.dias = [];
    vm.mensajeError = '';
    vm.cargarHorarios = cargarHorarios;
    vm.guardarHorarioInicial = guardarHorarioInicial;
    vm.guardarHorarioFinal = guardarHorarioFinal;
    vm.horariosInicial = [];
    vm.horariosFinal = [];

    inicializar();

    function inicializar() {
        cargarHorarios();

    }

    //guardar todos los horarios del primer turno
    function guardarHorarioInicial(index){
        //horariosInicial[index] = 
        console.log("indexxxxxx:"+index);
        console.log("Option 1 : " + $scope.selectedOption1);
        debugger;
        //vm.horarios[index] = vm.test[index];

    }

    //guardar todos los horarios del último turno
    function guardarHorarioFinal(index){
        console.log("indexxxxxx:"+index);
        console.log("Option 1 : " + $scope.selectedOption1);
        debugger;
        //vm.horarios[index] = vm.test[index];

    }

}
})();
```

But the console display:

> indexxxxxx : 0
>   Option 1 : undefined

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have a controller, but I did not put anything on it, because I don't know

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` here. Here's a code example for your scenario

```
  <p>Selected Option 1 : </p>
  <select ng-model="selectedOption1" ng-options="x for x in names">   </select>


  <p>Selected Option 2 : </p>
  <select ng-model="selectedOption2" ng-options="x for x in names">   </select>

  <p>Submit Button</p>
  <button ng-click=submitOptions()>SUBMIT</button>

  <p>Option1 : {{selectedOption1}} </p>
  <p>Option2 : {{selectedOption2}} </p>
```

And javascript controller looks like this

```
   $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"]; 

   $scope.submitOptions = function(){
     console.log("Option 1 : " + $scope.selectedOption1);
     console.log("Option 2 : " + $scope.selectedOption2);
}
```

Here what it do is that it would fill up both `<select>` tags with options in `$scope.names`. Here in your case values in `dia.horarios` 
Each`<select>` are selected value is bind to individual model. Here in option 1 is bind to `$scope.selectedOption1`. You will be able to use `$scope.selectedOption1` and `$scope.selectedOption2` values as selected values!

---

**IN RESPONSE OF EDIT**
By Default *select* will not be selecting any option and I guess that is the reason for empty value. Try code below.

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption1" ng-options="x for x in names" ng-change="changed($index)>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.changed = function(index){
    console.log($scope.selectedOption1);
}
```

Another reason for undefined might be function on the controller not using $scope. Dont know for sure but this works as needed.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Chathuranga94, but I need to show the option dynamically, so now I have 14 options but tomorrow may be I have 10.

Comment: And $scope.selectedOption1 and $scope.selectedOption2 only get 2 options (but I have like 14 options). May be I did not understand you. Change ng-repeat for ng-options I understand

Comment: <select ng-repeat="i in ...num of types..."  ng-model="selectedOption[i]" ng-options=.........>

Comment: ng repeat should repeat number of times needed while ng-model will bind to array of $scope.selectedOptions

Comment: @FederickJons changed answer according to edit. Check that out. And mark this as answer if you find this useful

Answer (score 0):

please follow the following steps may be it will help you to solve your problem.

1. please use  ng-change function for each select box and push the selected values into one array you can put ng-change function in repeater also..
2. then you will get the all selected values into single array then user click on Guardar cambios then call service to update the details.